# How to remove the letters from float value in android?

Tags: java, android

I have some issue like this

in my textview Rs. 99.99

```
String val = textview.getText().toString();
```

Result :: val :: `Rs.99.99`

i am converting that into float using this way

```
float value = Float.parseFloat(val);
```

i am getting `NumberFormatException`: Rs.99.99 cannot convert

any one guide me

Comment: You need to take substring and then convert it into float.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following before converting it to float

```
String substring = str.length() > 2 ? str.substring(str.length() - 3) : str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.

```
System.out.println(Float.parseFloat("Rs.99.99".substring(3)));
```

**Note:** You need to make sure the string always contain "**Rs.**" in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

> i am getting numberFormat Exception Rs.99.99 cannot convert

Yes, because in method

```
Float.parseFloat(String s);
```

You get

```
NumberFormatException -- if the string does not contain a parsable float.
```

And In your case it isn't,

So best option is to  apply Validation to enter only floating point numbers inside text View.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what the problem is (do all the strings that cause problems begin with `Rs.`, or are users putting other kinds of garbage at the beginning of the input)?  Here's a way to remove all characters from the string, up to (but not including) the first digit:

```
val = val.replaceFirst("^[^0-9]*", "");
```

This finds the first occurrence of a pattern that starts at the beginning of the string (the first `^`) and consists of 0 or more occurrences of nondigits (`[^0-9]`).